# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, .net-assembly

I am trying o open a windows project and I am seeing this error, The project works fine but I am unable to see forms design due to this error.

[image]

I tried many solutions like adding assemblies, opening project from .csproj file, opening from solution file, adding all missing references but still same error on design window. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: May it be a version missmatch? Again what .Net version do you build?

Comment: @Jitender Dhaliwal, Based on my research, I suggest that you could create a new windows form app to check if you still have the problem. If so, I suggest that you could use visual studio installer to repair your visual studio.

Comment: Other forms in same project all are working just this one form is showing this error. I am not sure what is going on here. I will keep looking. Thank you for the suggestions.